# Scraping information from a webpage using the rvest library in R

Tags: r, web-scraping, xpath, caching, rvest

**Example**: Scrape the first poster title from this [webpage](https://www.aiche.org/academy/conferences/synthetic-biology-engineering-evolution-design-seed/2021/proceeding/session/poster-presenters-accepted).

[image]

I have:

- selected the title
- right-clicked and inspected it in the Developer Tools
- copied the Xpath

Here is my code:

```
    url   <- "https://www.aiche.org/academy/conferences/synthetic-biology-engineering-evolution-design-seed/2021/proceeding/session/poster-presenters-accepted"
    xpath <- "/html/body/div[1]/div[5]/section/div[2]/div/div[2]/div/div[3]/div/div/article/div/div/div[2]/div[2]/div[1]/div[1]/div[2]/span/a"

    url %>%
     read_html() %>%
     html_element(xpath = xpath) %>%
     html_text()
```

**Question**: Why don't I always extract the first title?

[image]

Comment: When you refresh the order of paper is changing

Comment: Yes, I have just noticed ! Thx !

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The simple answer is that the response body of the page that you are evaluating is changing between requests. When I load that URL into a browser and force the page to reload (`Command+Shift+R` for Chrome on Mac, `Control+F5` for Windows) several times, a different version of the page is displayed.

First:
[image: Version you think you are requesting]

Second:
[image: Alternative version of the same page]

The longer answer is that it appears these two variations of the page are being returned due to the site having caching misconfigured, load balancing misconfigured, or a combination of both.

I arrived at this conclusion by looking at the response headers of several requests. The `Via` header's value is `varnish`. [Varnish](https://varnish-cache.org/intro/index.html#intro) is an HTTP caching reverse proxy. I also noticed that the `X-Cache` header value was `HIT` and that for both versions of the page, but the `X-Cache-Hits` and `Content-Length` values varied. Out of the box, when Varnish sets the `X-Cache` header to `HIT`, it means that it is returning a cached copy from memory. The `X-Cache-Hits` header is basically a counter for the number of times a particular cached page has been returned.

There isn't much that you can do about caching issues without performing cache-busting requests which might be considered abusive by the site's owner.